# Entity Framework - Sorting Relationproperties

Tags: wpf, frameworks, entity

my question is, how do I sort related items of an entity.

In an invoice editing window, I have one ComboBox displaying all customers:

XAML:

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvsCustomers" 
                              d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance local:Customer, CreateList=True}" />
...

    </UserControl.Resources>

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsCustomers}}" .../>
```

Code-behind:

```
Dim cvsCustomers As System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource
cvsCustomers = CType(Me.FindResource("cvsCustomers"), System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)

Dim qryCustomers = _
            From c In myEntities.Customers _
            Order By c.CustomerCode
            Select c
        cvsCustomers.Source = qryCustomers
```

Now I have a 2nd ComboBox displaying all contact persons of the selected customer. This works fine, but the entries in this second ComboBox are unsorted / sorted by ID.

XAML:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=myInvoice.Customer.Contacts}" .../>
```

;

How do I get the list on the 2nd ComboBox sorted?

King regards,
and thanks in advance for tips/suggestions,

Nico

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two possible things.

- **When loading the data**: It sounds like you are using the lazyloading feature of EF to load the `Contacts` related to the `Customer`. To sort Contacts, you would need to set what is sort option, were it's and when it's, but with the lazyloading these cannot be set. So you can use the Eagerly loading or the Explicitly loading to get the `Contacts` ordered. Please check to [Using DbContext in EF 4.1 Part 6: Loading Related Entities](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/31/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-6-loading-related-entities.aspx), based on EF4.1. Something like this, the Explicitly loading case:

  ```
  //Oh, I'm not familiar with VB.NET, so it's C# code
  var customer; // it's assumed to be initialized.
  context.Entry(customer).Collection(c => w.Contacts)
  .Query().Orderby(c =>c.Name).Load();
  ```
- **Through `CollectionView` after loading the data unordered**: you can let the `CollectionView` order the `Contacts`. Please check to [CollectionViewSource Class(MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.aspx).

Comment: beware, `context.Entry(instance)` is slow as... Turtle :)